# How to use Google API's (in JAVA) for fetching a specific row/column in a spreadsheet?

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I am writing a code in which I need to access a particular column of a spreadsheet, already uploaded on my GDrive. I have found the Java API that is required for my project.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#fetching_specific_rows_or_columns

I have have already installed : Mercurial, Maven and Google PlugIn for eclipse, as well.

Now when I run my code, the following error comes : " *The type com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"*.

According to me this error is might be because of the path/URL given in the google API to access a particular spreadsheet :

***URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");***

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Can you please post your build.gradle file? Also, please make sure your project is synchronized with gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the required Google Data API Client libraries downloaded or not? If not, make sure those libraries are downloaded and check this [link](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/java_client_lib)

It seems this is the dependency: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gdata/core/1.47.1

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Spreadsheets API documentation ([Fetching specific rows or columns](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#fetching_specific_rows_or_columns)) suggests the following...being worksheet the specific worksheet instance of your spreadsheet, and let's say 6 the column list of values that you want to get:

```
        URL cellFeedUrl = new URI(worksheet.getCellFeedUrl().toString() +
                "?min-row=2&min-col=6&max-col=6").toURL();

        CellFeed cell = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);

        for(CellEntry eachCellEntry : cell.getEntries()){
            // prints value of each cell in column 6 but the title
            log.info(eachCellEntry.getCell().getValue());
        }
```

I don't like the passing of the hard coded arguments in a String manually for the URL when using CellFeed...like min-row, min-col, max-col...I am trying to find a better way to do this, perhaps using a query.